# Displaying a picture in an email (VB)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Any ideas on the correct syntax for the following..

```
bodyText.AppendLine(<img src='ltlItems.Text' /></a>)
```

The url is stored in ltlItems.Text

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the & to concatenate your values:

```
bodyText.AppendLine("<img src='" & ltlItems.Text & "' /></a>")
```